# How to conditionally include a sub-app with Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using a library called [Grant](https://github.com/simov/grant) in my application.  Previously I have included it following the examples in the readme linked above, however I now have the need to conditionally include it and I can't seem to make it work.

**How it worked before**

```
const grant = new Grant(grantConfig);
app.use(grant);
```

I've done conditional middleware in Express before, so I thought including Grant wouldn't be a problem.

**How I Tried (doesn't work)**

```
const grant = new Grant(grantConfig);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (someBooleanVariable) {
        next();
    } else {
        grant(req, res, next);
    }
});
```

So this doesn't work.  I think it may have something to do with Grant being an instance of Express versus just a regular middleware function, but I'm not sure.  You can see how Grant is implemented [here](https://github.com/simov/grant/blob/master/lib/consumer/express.js).  The Express docs say that it should be treated the same, but I might also be misunderstanding them.

*Note:  I need this to work on per-request basis, hence the middleware style approach.*

Comment: have you tried app.use(grant); inside this else statement?

Comment: Do you really need to use it on a per-request basis, or do you need it for specific routes only?

Comment: app.use(grant) didn't work when I tried it.  Ideally I need to use it on a subset of routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a particular middleware on only a subset of routes:

```
// On a single route:
app.get('/some/route', grant, function(req, res) {
  ...
});

// On a set of routes with a particular prefix:
app.use('/api', grant, apiRouter);

// On a specific router:
let apiRouter = express.Router();

apiRouter.use(grant);
apiRouter.get(...);
```